# Почему redis ничего не сохраняет неделями при дефолтном конфиге?

Tags: redis

На двух разных компах замечено странное одинаковое поведение, стоковый redis 2.8.4, с дефолтным конфигом, и данные неделями остаются в оперативке не скидываются в dump.rdb.

В конфиге указано:

```
save 900 1
save 300 10
save 60 10000
```

Но ничего не сбрасывается на диск неделями пока не наберёшь `SAVE` в клиенте redis-cli. Количество изменённых записей больше 10, но намного меньше чем 10000, может дело в этом, и Редис использует только последнее упоминание опции `save` в конфиге?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis использует *все* упоминания save. В данном случае, он сбрасывает данные на диск в любом из трех случаев:

1. если в течение промежутка времени в 15 минут изменился хотя бы один ключ;
2. если в течение промежутка времени в 5 минут изменилось минимум десять ключей;
3. если в течение промежутка времени в 1 минуту изменилось минимум 10'000 ключей.

Разные упоминания используются для обработки разных случаев интенсивности нагрузки (нет смысла сохраняться часто, если изменения в базе крайне редки, и, наоборот, если интенсивность очень большая, лучше бы сохраняться почаще).

Судя по этому конфигу, как минимум раз в 15 минут, если хоть что-то в базе меняется, все должно сохраняться, и лично я проблем с этим не наблюдал. Скажите, как вы определяете что данные скидываются/не скидываются? dbfilename точно установлен в dump.rdb? Вы смотрите в директорию, указанную в параметре конфигурации dir?

Comment: `/var/lib/redis/dump.rdb` существует, и если набрать `SAVE` то всё мгновенно в нём оказывается, можно проверить `grep` (найти какой-нибуть свежевбитый ключ) или по дате+размеру файла. У нас один сервер (тестовый к счастью) был перезапущен и после перезапуска обнаружили, что нет ключей за последний месяц, при дефолтном конфиге.

Comment: Если еще актуально. У dump.rdb должен быть правильные права `redis:redis 644`